# Linq To Entities Indirect Contextual Table Join in Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-fluent-api

I am using pure Fluent API Code-First.  I do not use Attributes on my Entities, and I keep my contexts seperate.  I have an `OrderEntity` which has a One To Many relationship to `OrderDetails`, joined by `OrderID`.  Therefore, I have An `EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderDetailEntity>` which has the following:

```
HasRequired(x => x.Order).WithMany(x => x.Details);
HasRequired(x => x.Item);
```

An Item has a relationship with its Prices.  But the relationship is a Cartesian. One Item has 200+ `ItemPrices` associated with it. `ItemPrice` looks like this:

```
public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
public int PriceTypeID { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

There are 3 `PriceTypes`, and dozens of Currencies.

I consider it appropriate for `ItemPrice` to define the relationship between Item and `ItemPrice` like so:

```
HasRequired(x => x.Item).WithMany(x => x.ItemPrices);
```

An Item **Does Not** have a Currency Code or `Price` Type.  An Item is just an item, and the Currency Code and Price Type are determined at the time the `Order` is placed.  Those two variables are on the Order.  So, to determine the price of an order, I have this:

SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN Items item ON od.ItemID = item.ItemID
INNER JOIN ItemPrices itemPrice ON item.ItemID = itemPrice.ItemID AND o.CurrencyCode = itemPrice.CurrencyCode AND o.PriceTypeID = itemPrice.PriceTypeID
```

And Linq:

```
context.Orders
.Join(context.OrderDetails,
    o => o.OrderID,
    od => od.OrderID,
    (o, od) => new { o, od })
.Join(context.Items,
    o2od => o2od.od.ItemID,
    item => item.ItemID,
    (o2od, item) => new { o2od, item })
.Join(context.ItemPrices,
    o2od2item => new { o2od2item.item.ItemID, o2od2item.o2od.o.CurrencyCode, o2od2item.o2od.o.PriceType },
    itemPrice => new { itemPrice.ItemID, itemPrice.CurrencyCode, itemPrice.PriceType },
    (o2od2item, itemPrice) => new { o2od2item, itemPrice })
```

**Long-Story Short**: There is an indirect relationship between the `Order` and the `ItemPrice`, in the context regarding calculating an `Order`'s price.

All of my other LINQ is beautiful and using the navigation properties correctly and such.  Is there a way to define this contextual relationship in Fluent API and use it when my LINQ has Order -> Detail -> Item -> Price ?  Or do I have to do a manual definition of the relationship every time?

Answer (score 2):

Applying my SQL brain to Linq, I remember that most simple Joins can be moved into the WHERE Clause.  So while this doesn't help to define the contextual relationship between Order and ItemPrices in Fluent API, it does allow me to use clean Linq without Joins like so:

```
context.Orders
.Where(x => orderIDs.Contains(x.OrderID)
    && x.Details.Any(y => 
        y.Item.ItemPrices.Any(z =>
            && z.CurrencyCode == x.CurrencyCode 
            && z.PriceType == x.PriceType
    )))
```

While I would rather describe the relationship between tables in different contexts, this LINQ Query fulfills my need to rely on navigation properties instead of joins.